# Help with calculating the integral $\int_0^a \sqrt{x^3 + 1}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, arc-length

How to evaluate the following integral analytically?
$$
\int_0^a \sqrt{x^3 + 1}\,dx
$$
Here, $a = \sqrt[3]{63}$.

This integral represents the area between curves. Note that it can also be reduced to the calculation of the arc length for the function $y = y(x)$:
$$
y = \frac{2}{5}x^{5/2},\quad x \in [0, 63^{1/3}].
$$

As Wolfram Alpha suggests, this integral probably can't be expressed in elementary functions.
Could you describe an approach for analytical integration?

Comment: It can't be expressed in elementary functions because $y^2=x^3+1$ is an elliptic curve (so has genus $1$) and one can only parametrize rationally rational (genus $0$) curves.

Comment: @Sonner How can the answer be obtained in terms of special functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $y=\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^{3}
 $, then $$I=\frac{a}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+ya^{3}}y^{-\frac{2}{3}}dy
 $$  and now we can recognize [the integral representation of the Hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) $$I=a\,_{2}F_{1}\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3};\frac{4}{3};-a^{3}\right)$$ and I don't think we can do much more.